# Reference for theorem about completion of locally convex topological algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

I am studying Jen-Pierre Demailly's "Complex Analytic and Diferential Geometry" and in definition (5.39) the author implies that a locally convex topological algebra $A$ (i.e. a locally convex space that has a continuous commutative multiplication operation and a multiplicative identity) has a completion, i.e., there is a complete locally convex topological algebra $\tilde{A}$ that has $A$ as a dense subspace. However, I'm not being able to find any reference with a theorem that guarantees this. I know that for locally convex spaces, there is a nice theorem about the existence of completion, and I assume there is also one for locally convex topological algebras, since it seems to be used in the book.

Can anyone help me? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Since $A$ is also a locally convex topological vector space, we can take its vector space completion $\tilde{A}$. Then it's just a question of showing that the multiplication operation extends. Since the vector space completion is unique, if there is a completion as an algebra, it must be the vector space completion. I'm not sure how hard it is to show that multiplication extends though (you would want some kind of uniform continuity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the product in a (locally convex) topological algebra $\mathfrak{A}$ (we assume from now on that $\mathfrak{A}$ is Hausdorff) is usually only required to be *separately* continuous, i.e. if you fix either argument of the product you end up with a continuous linear map from $\mathfrak{A}$ to itself. If $\mathfrak{A}$ is barrelled and metrizable (e.g. if $\mathfrak{A}$ is Fréchet), then its product is (jointly) continuous, but there are examples of locally convex algebras where this fails - take e.g. the tensor algebra generated by the space of smooth real-valued functions with compact support on a non-void open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

*Joint* continuity of the multiplication indeed is a sufficient condition for it to extend to the completion, and in this case the extension also happens to be jointly continuous, see e.g. Theorème 1, pp. III.50-III.51 of N. Bourbaki, *Topologie Générale, Chapitres 1-4* (Springer-Verlag, 2007). If the multiplication is only separately continuous, it may not be possible to extend the multiplication to the completion.

A middle-ground result can be obtained after some preparation. Let $E,F,G$ be topological vector spaces, and $\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{N}$ be families of bounded subsets of respectively $E,F$. We say that a bilinear map $T:E\times F\rightarrow G$ is $(\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{N})$*-hypocontinuous* if for any $0$-neighborhood $V$ in $G$ there are $U_1\subset E$, $U_2\subset F$ $0$-neighborhoods and $K_1\in\mathfrak{M}$, $K_2\in\mathfrak{N}$ such that $T(U_1,K_2),T(K_1,U_2)\subset V$. If $\mathfrak{M}$ (resp $\mathfrak{N}$) covers $E$ (resp. $F$), then a $(\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{N})$-hypocontinuous bilinear map $T:E\times F\rightarrow G$ is, of course, separately continuous - this is the case if e.g. $\mathfrak{M}$ (resp $\mathfrak{N}$) is the family of all finite or all bounded subsets of $E$ (resp. $F$) - and $(\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{N})$*-(bi)bounded*, that is, if $K_1\in\mathfrak{M}$, $K_2\in\mathfrak{N}$, then $T(K_1,K_2)$ is a bounded subset of $G$. If $\mathfrak{M}$ (resp. $\mathfrak{N}$) is the family of *all* bounded subsets of $E$ (resp. $F$), we simply say that a $(\mathfrak{M},\mathfrak{N})$-hypocontinuous bilinear map $T$ is *hypocontinuous*. If $E,F$ are barrelled, then any separately continuous bilinear map $T:E\times F\rightarrow G$ is hypocontinuous.

Now we are in a position to state the result (see e.g. Theorem 4.2, pp. 30 of the book of A. Mallios, *Topological Algebras, Selected Topics* (North-Holland, 1986)):

> **Theorem:** Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be a locally convex (Hausdorff) algebra. If the product of $\mathfrak{A}$ is *hypocontinuous*, then it admits a *separately continuous* extension to the *sequential* completion $\widetilde{\mathfrak{A}}_\sigma$ of $\mathfrak{A}$. In other words, $\widetilde{\mathfrak{A}}_\sigma$ is a locally convex algebra.

Sometimes it happens that $\widetilde{\mathfrak{A}}_\sigma$ coincides with the completion of $\mathfrak{A}$ even if the latter's topology is not first countable. An important example is the space of smooth functions with compact support on a non-void open subset $U$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ endowed with the strong topology when dually paired with itself. This topology is clearly not first countable, but the sequential completion of this space is the space of distributions on $U$ endowed with the strong topology, which is complete.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it was very helpful. Especially since I'm not very familiar with this subject, I was just using these concepts in a project. I do have one question: If I have a topological algebra $A$ whose topology is induced by a unique (multiplicative) semi-norm, then it is metrizable, but is it barreled?

Comment: If that seminorm is not a norm, then the topology is not even Hausdorff, let alone metrizable. If it's a norm, a sufficient condition for barrelledness is that the topology is complete, of course. A weaker condition is that the topology should be ultrabornological - i.e. the underlying locally convex vector space is an inductive limit of Banach spaces, but even that is not automatic with just the hypothesis of a unique norm. However, you already said your (semi)norm is *submultiplicative* - that alone ensures that the multiplication is (jointly) continuous, regardless of anything else.

Comment: Yes, of course you're right. I was getting confused with something